# Changing state of one element in a loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to show image on a click. How to do this in a loop? Every image has a state at the start:

```
imgDisplay: 'none'
```

Then I'm changing it on a click, but on every element in a loop. How to change it for a single element?

```
handleShowPhoto = () => {
    this.setState({
        imgDisplay: 'block'
    });
};

            <tr key={photo.id}>
                <td><a href="#" onClick={this.handleShowPhoto}>{photo.title}</a></td>
                <td><img style={{display: this.state.imgDisplay}} src={photo.thumbnailUrl} alt=""/></td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: your code doesn't preset the problem...

Comment: Can you frame your question a little better?  I'm thinking you mean you want to hide all other images, and show only one.  Meaning you want to remove the `display:block` from all images that you didn't click.  Though... yeah need to frame question a little better.

Comment: Is it clear now? Yeah, I have to use display:block only on one image.

Comment: @Neil I think that's much better :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, so you need to pass the clicked ID to the state then compear it with the current state like:

```
    handleShowPhoto = (data) => {
        this.setState({
            //imgDisplay: 'block', no need for this
            clickedID: data.id // create clickedID in state constructor as a string like clickedID: '' or null
        });
    };


        <tr key={photo.id}>
            <td><a href="#" onClick={this.handleShowPhoto.bind(this, photo)}>{photo.title}</a></td>
            <td><img style={photo.id === this.state.clickedID ? {display: 'block'} : {display: 'none'}} src={photo.thumbnailUrl} alt=""/></td>
        </tr>
```

if you want to make `handleShowPhoto` Toggle and handling multiple images your code should be like:

We will do that using: [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) , [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) , [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```
    handleShowPhoto = (data) => {  clickedID should be an array in construcor like clickedID: []
     if(this.state.clickedID.indexOf(photo.id) !== -1){
        this.setState(prevState=>({ clickedID: prevState.clickedID.filter(id => id !== data.id)] })) //deleting clicked ID if it's already exist
     }else{
        this.setState(prevState=>({ clickedID: [...prevState.clickedID, data.id] })) adding new id 
     }
    };

      <tr key={photo.id}>
            <td><a href="#" onClick={this.handleShowPhoto.bind(this, photo)}>{photo.title}</a></td>
            <td><img style={this.state.clickedID.indexOf(photo.id) !== -1 ? {display: 'block'} : {display: 'none'}} src={photo.thumbnailUrl} alt=""/></td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: I wanted to try this, but console shows that indexOf is undefined, but it works awesome with just one image.

Comment: Well, please make sure `clickedID` state is an array in constructor like `clickedID: []`

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use jQuery to select a list of elements, then loop over that list and set their state accordingly.  Finally, set the "this" one to display: block like you already do.

```
handleShowPhoto = () => {
    var allElements = jQuery('selector').each(function(){
        this.setState({
            imgDisplay: 'none'
        });
    });
    this.setState({
        imgDisplay: 'block'
    });
};
```

I'd replace "selector" with something like '#myTable > td > img', you're trying to get a list of the img tags.

Forgive any syntax errors, I'm not using an IDE atm :)